# How to find the first number in a text field using a MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, regex

I like to return only the first number of a text stored in a column of a database table.
User have put in page ranges into a field like 'p.2-5' or 'page 2 to 5' or '2 - 5'.
I am interested in the '2' here.

I tried to

```
  SELECT SUBSTR(the_field, LOCATE('2', the_field, 1)) AS 'the_number'
  FROM the_table
```

and it works. But how to get ANY number?

I tried

```
  SELECT SUBSTR(the_field, LOCATE(REGEXP '[0-9], the_field, 1)) AS 'the_number'
  FROM the_table
```

but this time I get an error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your regexp pattern is missing a quote `'`

Comment: `REGEXP` in mysql is for pattern matching not extraction ... you could extract the required number using a server side language easier

Answer (score 1):

Just use [REGEXP_SUBSTR()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-substr):

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(`the_field`,'^[0-9]+') AS `the_number` FROM `the_table`;
```

Notes:

1. I'm using MySQL Server v8.0.
2. This pattern assumes that `the_field` is trimmed. Otherwise, use TRIM() first.

Answer (score 0):

`REGEXP` is not a function in MySQL, but something of an operator. Returns `1` if field matches the regular expression, or `0` if it does not. You cannot use it to figure out a position in a string.

Usage:

```
mysql> SELECT 'Monty!' REGEXP '.*';
    -> 1
```

As for answer to the question: I don't think there is a simple way to do that using MySQL only. You would be better off processing that field in the code, or extract values before inserting.

Answer (score 0):

For the specific case in the question. Where the String is {number}{string}{number}
there is a simple solution to get the first number. In our case we had numbers like `1/2,3`
`4-10`
`1,2`
and we were looking for the first number in each row.

It turned out that for this case one can use `convert` function to convert it into number. `MySQL` will return the first number

`select convert(the_field ,SIGNED) as the_first_number from the_table`

or more hard core will be

```
SELECT
the_field,
@num := CONVERT(the_field, SIGNED) AS cast_num,
SUBSTRING(the_field, 1, LOCATE(@num, the_field) + LENGTH(@num) - 1) AS num_part,
SUBSTRING(the_field, LOCATE(@num, the_field) + LENGTH(@num)) AS txt_part
FROM the_table;
```

**This was original post at  [source](http://grokbase.com/t/mysql/mysql/054ph638hw/extract-numeric-value-from-a-string) by Eamon Daly**

### What does it do?

1. `@num := CONVERT(the_field, SIGNED) AS cast_num` # try to convert it into a number
2. `SUBSTRING(the_field, 1, LOCATE(@num, the_field) + LENGTH(@num) - 1)` # gets the number by using the length and the location of @num in field
3. `SUBSTRING(the_field, LOCATE(@num, the_field) + LENGTH(@num))` # finds the rest of the string after the number.

### Some thoughts for future use

Its worth  keeping another `column` which will hold the first number after you parsed it before insert it to the database. Actually this is what we are doing these days.

### Edit

Just saw that you have text like `p.2-5` and etc.. which means the above cannot work as if the string  does not start with a number `convert` return zero

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in way that I know of, but here's a Mysql function you can define, this will do it (I didn't code for minus-signs or non-integers, but those could of course be added).

Once created, you can use it like any other function:

```
SELECT firstNumber(the_field) from the_table;
```

Here's the code:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION firstNumber(s TEXT)
    RETURNS INTEGER
    COMMENT 'Returns the first integer found in a string'
    DETERMINISTIC
    BEGIN

    DECLARE token TEXT DEFAULT '';
    DECLARE len INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE ind INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE thisChar CHAR(1) DEFAULT ' ';

    SET len = CHAR_LENGTH(s);
    SET ind = 1;
    WHILE ind <= len DO
        SET thisChar = SUBSTRING(s, ind, 1);
        IF (ORD(thisChar) >= 48 AND ORD(thisChar) <= 57) THEN
            SET token = CONCAT(token, thisChar);
        ELSEIF token <> '' THEN
            SET ind = len + 1;
        END IF;
        SET ind = ind + 1;
    END WHILE;

    IF token = '' THEN
        RETURN 0;
    END IF;

    RETURN token;

    END //
DELIMITER ;
```