# return numbers from the middle of a string with irregular format

Tags: mysql, regex, string, substring

I have a field in a MySQL database that contains item descriptions of purchased products. Some of these are descriptions in plain English, others are part numbers, and others still are part numbers followed by a description. I have removed all spaces and dashes from the strings with a replace().

> data looks like this:

```
1938420985390asdfih
1234812934810dflkasd
asdfasldkjfaasdfjasd
asd;flkjaklsdf
adfsdf1234073927357sdapjfas
1/4sdikhsd
```

> and I would like to return:

```
1938420985390
1234812934810
(null)
(null)
1234073927357
(null)
```

What I really need is to write a SQL that will return the 13 digit part numbers, but not the extra letters/characters. I would prefer that it return the actual number, too, rather than a 1 or 0 for match/ no match.

I tried using a REGEXP function (someone suggested `regexp ('\d{13}')` or `regexp ('\p{13}')` but these didn't work. [These returned a 0 or 1, and not the part of the string that matched.] Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you define how those regular expressions didn't work? Were there errors? Did the results come back without errors but empty?

Comment: @Corey: I'm pretty sure what OP meant was that the REGEXP expression returned a 1 or a 0, rather than return the portion of the value that matched the pattern. (MySQL doesn't have a builtin function to return the matched string.)

Comment: @CoreyOgburn: spencer is correct...the issue is that it would return a 1 or a 0. I could then use a unique ID to link back out to the column values, but the idea is to try and match part numbers to another data set. I could also do this with the other data set: concat("or item_desc like '%", part_number, "%'") and then run a massive query that way, but it would take forever...and not to mention the other data set is not exhaustive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a non-trivial task in MySQL, there's no builtin function for returning a regular expression match.  But because you are looking for exactly 13 digits, you could do something like this (obviously extend this to the number of positions you need to check...

```
-- setup test
CREATE TABLE t (foo VARCHAR(30));
INSERT INTO t VALUES 
('1938420985390asdfih')
,('1234812934810dflkasd')
,('asdfasldkjfaasdfjasd')
,('asd;flkjaklsdf')
,('adfsdf1234073927357sdapjfas')
,('1/4sdikhsd')


SELECT CASE
       WHEN SUBSTR(foo,1,13) REGEXP '^[0-9]{13}$' THEN SUBSTR(foo,1,13)
       WHEN SUBSTR(foo,2,13) REGEXP '^[0-9]{13}$' THEN SUBSTR(foo,2,13)
       WHEN SUBSTR(foo,3,13) REGEXP '^[0-9]{13}$' THEN SUBSTR(foo,3,13)
       WHEN SUBSTR(foo,4,13) REGEXP '^[0-9]{13}$' THEN SUBSTR(foo,4,13)
       WHEN SUBSTR(foo,5,13) REGEXP '^[0-9]{13}$' THEN SUBSTR(foo,5,13)
       WHEN SUBSTR(foo,6,13) REGEXP '^[0-9]{13}$' THEN SUBSTR(foo,6,13)
       WHEN SUBSTR(foo,7,13) REGEXP '^[0-9]{13}$' THEN SUBSTR(foo,7,13)
       WHEN SUBSTR(foo,8,13) REGEXP '^[0-9]{13}$' THEN SUBSTR(foo,8,13)
       WHEN SUBSTR(foo,9,13) REGEXP '^[0-9]{13}$' THEN SUBSTR(foo,9,13)
       END AS digits
  FROM t

-------------------
1938420985390
1234812934810
(NULL)
(NULL)
1234073927357
(NULL)
```

No, it's not pretty. But you should be able to extend this to effectively "scan" a string of reasonable length.

NOTE: The regular expression is checking that the whole 13 character substring consists of exactly 13 characters, each of the characters is a decimal digit (0 thru 9).

Comment: This works with NULL values, empty strings, and for strings less than 13 characters.  This will basically find the first occurrence of 13 consecutive digits within the string. You'll need to repeat the WHEN line, to include checks starting at positions 10, 11, 12, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Getting back your matched values may not yet be supported in MySQL as described here - [MySQL Regular Expressions with The REGEXP Operator](http://www.regular-expressions.info/mysql.html). However as mentioned in the link, there are 3rd party libs that you could use like this one: [UDF Repository for MySQL](http://www.mysqludf.org/lib_mysqludf_preg/), which allows you to capture matches using `PREG_CAPTURE`.

For some more information, this [StackOverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361457/mysql-return-matching-pattern-in-regexp-query) seems to have dealt with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If each entry contains only one instance of numerical code then this one works:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN LENGTH(firstNumber(foo)) > 3 THEN firstNumber(foo) ELSE '' END AS result
FROM t
```

Two points worth to mention:

1. length of digits must be at least some length, let's say 3 digits, so that we can avoid results like 1 from row 6 '1/4sdikhsd';
2. The function [firstNumber](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9395178/how-to-find-the-first-number-in-a-text-field-using-a-mysql-query) is modified to return text but it is virtually the same:

   ```
   DELIMITER //
   CREATE FUNCTION firstNumber(s TEXT)
       RETURNS TEXT
       COMMENT 'Returns the first integer found in a string'
   DETERMINISTIC
   BEGIN

   DECLARE token TEXT DEFAULT '';
   DECLARE len INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
   DECLARE ind INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
   DECLARE thisChar CHAR(1) DEFAULT ' ';

   SET len = CHAR_LENGTH(s);
   SET ind = 1;
   WHILE ind <= len DO
       SET thisChar = SUBSTRING(s, ind, 1);
       IF (ORD(thisChar) >= 48 AND ORD(thisChar) <= 57) THEN
           SET token = CONCAT(token, thisChar);
       ELSEIF token <> '' THEN
           SET ind = len + 1;
       END IF;
       SET ind = ind + 1;
   END WHILE;

   IF token = '' THEN
       RETURN '';
   END IF;

   RETURN token;

   END //    DELIMITER ;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The function you are looking for is [REGEXP_SUBSTR()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-substr):

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(`dirty_value`,'[0-9]+') AS `clean_value` FROM `the_table`;
```

Note: I test it and works; I'm using MySQL Server v8.0 (not sure it worked in previous versions).

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

Instead of `mysql` you can do it easily with `grep` command in linux

```
grep [0-9] foo.txt
```

then create table and load it into mysql.