# MySQL order by first word in string

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My MySQL query gets motorcycle model names sorted by name
`SELECT * FROM models ORDER BY name`
i.e.:

```
[
'1200 Superenduro'
'250 ETC Enduro, silver',
'350 ETC 2014',
'450 ETC 2014',
'50 EC-X',
'690 ETC 2014',
'RS 1200 Superenduro'
]
```

The first word in the string is usually a number with engine capacity and I'd like to sort by this capacity. The expected output should be:

```
[
'50 EC-X',
'250 ETC Enduro, silver',
'350 ETC 2014',
'450 ETC 2014',
'690 ETC 2014',
'1200 Superenduro'
'RS 1200 Superenduro'
]
```

I tried to `ORDER BY` the first word, but looks like it doesn't really work:
`SELECT * FROM models ORDER BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, " ", 1)`. How to achieve proper sorting? I use MySQL 5.7. I may manipulate the output in PHP.

Comment: In the absence of a database solution, perhaps this csn help https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find the first number in a text field using a MySQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9395178/how-to-find-the-first-number-in-a-text-field-using-a-mysql-query)

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you can extract the first sequence of digits and convert to a number:

```
order by regexp_substr(name, '[0-9]+') + 0
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=10e82d504e52baa8321929c5d6c1ac28) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Unfortunately, I use 5.7 version and looks like `regexp_substr` doesn't exist there.

Comment: @feyen01 . . . That makes the problem much harder.

Answer (score 0):

you could add a custom function like this:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION firstNumber(s TEXT)
    RETURNS INTEGER
    COMMENT 'Returns the first integer found in a string'
    DETERMINISTIC
    BEGIN

    DECLARE token TEXT DEFAULT '';
    DECLARE len INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE ind INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE thisChar CHAR(1) DEFAULT ' ';

    SET len = CHAR_LENGTH(s);
    SET ind = 1;
    WHILE ind <= len DO
        SET thisChar = SUBSTRING(s, ind, 1);
        IF (ORD(thisChar) >= 48 AND ORD(thisChar) <= 57) THEN
            SET token = CONCAT(token, thisChar);
        ELSEIF token <> '' THEN
            SET ind = len + 1;
        END IF;
        SET ind = ind + 1;
    END WHILE;

    IF token = '' THEN
        RETURN 0;
    END IF;

    RETURN token;

    END //
DELIMITER ;
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9395178/how-to-find-the-first-number-in-a-text-field-using-a-mysql-query)

After you have to execute query in this way

```
SELECT * FROM models ORDER BY firstNumber(name)
```

(be aware that this sorting is not indexed)